# return html code from python script to html via flask (theory))

Tags: python, html, flask

I am just playing with python script (test.py) there is one function `test1()`.

```
def test1(): 
    return '<button (code ... for one simple button) .... ></button>'
```

In my **init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, url_for
import test

abc = test.test1()

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    try:
        return render_template('index.html', something=abc)
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In my index.html I have:

```
<body>
    {{something}}
</body>
```

Why html doesn't consider this variable as a code? If i copy `<button (code ... for one simple button) .... ></button>` to index.html directly and i just call reneder_template(index.html), everything is fine, however if i call this string from test.py html acts this is pure text within body tags... is there a way to fix this? Would appreciate it. Bascially, i would like html to read this string as a code not as a text.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/templating/#controlling-autoescaping

Comment: yes thank you Daniel

Comment: the link doesn't work anymore , this link works https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#autoescaping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<body>
{{something | safe}}
</body>
```

Comment: Lol high five, it works!